# Why size of the SSBitmapFontLabelNode can never be changed?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, glyph

I need to use bitmap fonts in my Sprite Kit based game and I'm using the Glyph designer. Setting node size for `SSBitmapFontLabelNode` won't change the size of the text inside it and although it's using `SSBitmapFont` which has a size property but it won't change the font size neither. I have the same problem using `bmglyph`.

Comment: you've created the font in a wrong way from the beginning perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

An SSBitmapFontLabelNode is just a transparent empty SKSpriteNode with all the glyphs as children, so setting the size has no effect.

Scaling up works well enough as long as you set linear filtering on.  Also make sure you have retina versions of your .skf files.

Make sure you have the latest [open source version of SSBitmapFont](https://forum.71squared.com/topic/63/ssbitmapfont-now-open-source) - drag the folder SSBitmapFont folder (from tvOSFontTest) into your project.

Set the scale of the font like this (Swift 3.0):

```
// Point size the font is to be displayed at
let desiredSize = CGFloat(42)

// Set to point size from GlyphDesigner 
let nativeSize = CGFloat(36)

let path = bundle.path(forResource: "Ancona-Ex", ofType:"skf")!
let fontUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
var labelFont: SSBitmapFont?
do {
    labelFont = try SSBitmapFont(file: fontUrl)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("\(path): \(error)"
}
let label = labelFont?.node(from: "My Label")
if (desiredSize != nativeSize) {
    label?.setTextureFilteringMode(SKTextureFilteringMode.linear)
    label?.setScale(desiredSize/nativeSize)
}
```